# Are jQuery created nodes fakes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have been fighting with this for hours, and yet it evades my comprehension...

```
var newLabel = $('<div></div>');
newLabel.appendTo("#f0");
console.log($("#f0").html());     // <br><div></div>
console.log(newLabel);            // [object Object]
var div = newLabel.first().get();
console.log(div);                 // [object HTMLDivElement]
if( div instanceof HTMLDivElement ) { console.log("VALID"); } // 
else { console.log("INVALID"); }  // INVALID
console.log(div.appendChild);     // undefined
```

We create a div element using jQuery and append it to a DOM element. It goes in, check. Object prints as "HTMLDivElement", check.

HOWEVER. It fails the instanceof. Also, it should have the method appendChild, but its undefined. (Indeed, it throws an error if I try to call it.)

What on earth is happening here? Is the element jQuery created for us, a fake?

Comment: `get()` returns an array, so `div` is an array in your case (which obviously is not an `HTMLDivElement` nor does it have a method `appendChild`). See: http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2. Try `.get(0)` instead.

Comment: if you want to see what something is on the console, use `console.dir(whatever)` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: Or better yet, just set a breakpoint in the code and inspect the variable directly.

Comment: @FelixKling: The problem with posting answers as comments is that the OP can't accept them.

Comment: Oh...? That explains a lot. Actually, it might be that my three-hour debugging spree just... ended. Thank you. Btw. I think that there is something fundamentally wrong about that it prints both a single object and a one-member array as "[object HTMLDivElement]".

Comment: @GolDDranks: LOL, yes. What you're seeing there is that `toString` on arrays is basically: Call `toString` on each element, then do a `Array#join`. But of course, when there's just one element, there's no comma to twig for you that there's more than one thing going on there... E.g.: `[1].toString()` is `"1"`, but `[1,2].toString()` is `"1,2"`.

Comment: @GolDDranks: What T.J. Crowder said. In addition, `console.log` could just be smarter and actually print additional information (like that the value is an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` returns an array, so `div` is an array in your case (which obviously is not an `HTMLDivElement` nor does it have a method `appendChild`). See: http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2. If you use `.get(0)` (or just `[0]`) instead, you'll get the actual `div` element.

Comment: *(This is just Felix Kling's comment -- with the* tiniest *addition -- posted as a CW [no rep generated] where the OP can accept it when the time comes.)*